# Simple HTML/CSS regarding thumbnails

Tags: html, css

I am new to web building. Currently following a tutorial for making an image gallery.
http://www.webreference.com/programming/css_gallery/index.html

It all works okish (enough for me to fix things to my liking) apart from the thumbnail section. Below is a snippet of the html and css for the thumbnails which I think is relevant to the help I seek. Basically, when you hover over the thumbnail, the main image will  appear in a free space in the page above. That kind of works (image doesnt appear in the right place, but I can fix that no probs) but the thumbnails are not displaying my images.

I changed the container div to "gallery" as I already have a container in my html, and dont want it to be affected by the new css following the tutorial...

html:

```
 <li> 
      <a class="gallery slidea" href="#nogo"> 
        <span> 
          <img src="images/Picture 014.jpg" alt="Wedding" title="Wedding" /> 
          <br /> 
          Wedding
      <br /> 
        Outside area wedding
        </span> 
      </a> 
    </li>
```

CSS:

```
#gallery a.slidea {
background:url(images/Picture 014 thumb.jpg);
height:38px;
width:50px;
}
```

Also for my CSS, the W3C validator says " #gallery a.slidea " Value Error : background Parse Error thumb.jpg)  which I dont understand.

Would love some help :D

Cheers

P.S I'm looking at putting this website onto wordpress (thats a tutorial I'll follow later on with more success I hope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
background:url(images/Picture 014 thumb.jpg);
```

That space is throwing it off. Put the url in quotes:

```
background:url('images/Picture 014 thumb.jpg');
```

The other problem is in your HTML.

Your CSS says `#gallery a.slidea`

This would point at all links with the class 'slidea' that are in an element with the id of 'gallery'. Your HTML indicates that the link is of class 'gallery' and 'slidea'. The right way to do it would depend on your goals.

Comment: Hi thanks for the picture help, I will try that!! (saying that I tried renaming the image, and the code so that there was no space e.g. pucture14thumb) but still didnt work. However, I will try the quotes.

I have lots of thumbs, and the css is like below, up to slidej

#gallery a.slidea {
    background:url(images/Picture 014 thumb.jpg);
    height:38px;
    width:50px;
    }
#gallery a.slideb {
    background:url(images/Picture 014 thumb.jpg);
    height:38px;
    width:50px;
    }

how do I enter code? properly?

Comment: The quotes help the image to show, but the size is wrong. Its like its been automatically enlargerd

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean, I think. The element you mention is the div where my images are, right? My code is just like it is in the turorial though, apart from the fact the "element" called gallery I have, its called container in the tutorial. The html in the tutorial for the links is exactly the same, except its in a container div. My div id is gallery. Will that be a potential problem?

Comment: You should keep everything exactly how it is in the tutorial. The CSS and HTML were written to work together, but if you change only one of them how could it possibly work the way it is intended? Once you learn more about how CSS and HTML work together then you can play around with it, but it sounds like you are just starting out with this stuff so you should stick as close to the tutorial as possible.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just starting out, the only reason things were changed was because I already have a container div, and I dont want the settings of the css for the gallery to affect that containing div, which is why I changed the name from container to gallery. Is it possible for me to have two style sheets loaded on one page and have one of them for the general styles (including my  first container) of the page, and then a second style sheet for the image gallery settings?

Comment: The name of the container can really be anything, but by using "gallery" you can see how it conflicts with your other styles.

Comment: Ok I changed the name of the container to imggallery, fixed up the css, and added the quotes to the picture link.. and it works. Hurray, thanks for everything!
Slowly understanding everything now!

Answer (score 0):

The call to the class doesnt match the name of the class

```
 <a class="gallery slidea" href="#nogo">
```

is calling

```
 #gallery a.slidea {
```

Try making them the same name, e.g.

```
 <a class="gallery_slide" href="#nogo"> 

 #gallery_slide a {
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. the class="gallery slidea" does match, doesnt it? the CSS is calling gallery slidea (slide a.. i have 12 thumbs, slidea slideb slidec etc etc)

Your change to the CSS will affect the fact it's a link, no? Isn't that what the #gallery a. bit is refering to?

I have 11 more lines of these two snippets of code each one changes slidea to slideb to slidec etc up to j.